# Como exibir jquery em php

Tags: php, jquery

Como exibir no `echo` do PHP o jQuery? Eu tentei fazer isso e não está dando certo:

```
public function InsereComentarioNoBanco($ip,$nome,$mensagem,$horario) {
    echo "
        <script>
            $('.nomeClas').hide();
            $('.nominho').hide();
        </script>
    ";

    $ConsultaDeInsercao = $this->pdo->query("insert into usuariochat SET mensagem = '$mensagem',nome = '$nome',horario = '$horario',ip = '$ip' ");

    if($ConsultaDeInsercao == true) {

            return "aff";
    }else { echo "ERRO NA INSERÇÃO DO COMENTÁRIO";}
```

Comment: Em que momento esse método é executado? Com base em que você afirma que não funciona? Qual foi o resultado obtido e qual era o esperado?

Comment: Assim que você dê enter nesse chat por exemplo , esse método vai ser chamado, enviando para o banco o comentario, e logo após vai mostrar o comentário naquela página da obscenidade. O esperado era a div sumir e não aconteceu nada.

Comment: Isso funciona? O que eu fiz é permitido ?????

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
//Nao esqueca o caminho do jquery.js

    function Hide() {
        console.log("ok");
        $('.nomeClas').hide();
        $('.nominho').hide();
    }

</script>

<?php
/*
 * Insere comentario
 */

function InsereComentarioNoBanco($ip, $nome, $mensagem, $horario)
{
    /*
     * Chama o function
     */
    echo "<script>Hide()</script>";

    $ConsultaDeInsercao = $this->pdo->query("insert into usuariochat SET mensagem = '$mensagem',nome = '$nome',horario = '$horario',ip = '$ip' ");

    if ($ConsultaDeInsercao == true) {

        return "aff";
    } else {
        echo "ERRO NA INSERÇÃO DO COMENTÁRIO";
    }
}
```